# Why the value of const changes when using generators?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I have been exploring Javascript generator and there is no issue in that but my doubt is how the generator is changing the value of 'const'. In my knowledge, if a variable is declared as const it can't be changed.

```
<script> 
function * numbers(i=0) 
{ 
    while(true){
        yield ++i;
    }

} 
const num = numbers(5);  ///// no error


console.log(num.next().value); 
console.log(num.next().value); 
console.log(num.next().value); 
</script>
```

```
output 
6 
7
8
```

Comment: because generator function returns a `generator` object, object's internal values can be changed even if the variable is defined with const

Comment: You can read [`Generator object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) also this [`generator function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Comment: `num` doesn't change to a different value? But of course, calling `.next()` can return different things on successive calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if a variable is declared as const it can't be changed.

What it *refers* to cannot be changed, it does not control the return values of functions or the mutability of objects.

In this specific case `const num = numbers(5)` assigns a generator *object* to `num`, now `num` will always refer to that same generator object, but that's where const's control ends - As soon as you start digging into `num`s properties (the `next()` method) you have left the initial reference behind, now you are using a different reference (`next` method on the `num` object), which returns another completely independent object with a property `value` - that is three references away from the original.

Even if you forgo all of the intermediate objects, const still has no control over a function's return value:

```js
let i = 0;

const foo = () => i ++;

foo(); // 0
foo(); // 1
foo(); // 2
```

const is about assignment, it only prevents this:

```js
const foo = () => i ++;

const foo = () => 0;

// SyntaxError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared
```

Generators are no different in this respect, they just have some special internal flow control.